# MediawikiPlayer extension not working for 3gp,mp4,mp3 extension

Tags: php, video, mediawiki, jwplayer, mediawiki-extensions

I am using this [extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MediawikiPlayer) in my mediawiki application . But it plays some files . Currently it is working only for **webm ogv and youtube videos** file format only but not **mp4 mp3 and flv**  .

for these files error is

> Error loading player: could not load player configuration

this is my embeded code

```
webm
<mediaplayer mode="packed">File:Small.webm</mediaplayer>
ogv
<mediaplayer mode="packed">http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv</mediaplayer>
mp4
<mediaplayer mode="packed">http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4</mediaplayer>
flv
<mediaplayer mode="packed">http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.flv</mediaplayer>
audio
<mp3player>File:Pakeezah2(www.songs.pk).mp3</mp3player>
```

I also tried to add configuration in `Localsetting.php`

```
$wgMWPlayerConfig = array( 
   'MyCustomConfig' => array ( 'width' => '900',
                               'height' => '300',
                               'allowfullscreen' => 'false',
                               'backcolor' => 'cccccc',
   ),
   'AnotherConfig' => array (  'width' => '600',
                               'height' => '400',
                               'allowfullscreen' => 'true',
                               'backcolor' => '000000',
   )
);

$wgMWPlayerDefaultSettings = array(
              'width' => '400',
              'height' => '300',
              'allowfullscreen' => 'true',
              'backcolor' => 'eeeeee',
              );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok guys here is the solution . I have found it [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/Mediaplayer/reply_(5))

step 1. download file from [midia-player-viral](http://www.mercantube.dk/player/mediaplayer-viral.zip/mediaplayer-viral/mediaplayer-5.8-viral/) and extract it.

step 2. download configuration file from [midiaplayer](http://swiftlytilting.com/files/MediawikiPlayer.0.3.0.zip)

extract it rename it to mediaplayer.

step 3. paste all the file from step 1 in the mediaplayer folder (step 2)

step 4. place the mediaplayer folder in /extension folder

step 5. add in local settings

```
require_once( "$IP/extensions/MediawikiPlayer/MediawikiPlayer.php" );
```

step 6. use it using syntax File:xyz.mp4